# Infinite right- and left-cancellable semigroup which is not a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I was given this question and the proof.

> Let $G$ be a nonempty set and let $*$ be an associative binary operation on $G$. Assume that both the left and right cancellation laws hold in $(G,*)$.
>
> Assume moreover that $G$ is *finite*. Show that $(G,*)$ is a group.

My question is why does the set have to be finite? What would happen if its the opposite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G$ is infinite, the conclusion is no longer true. You can find such examples in the literature, e.g., the positive (equally non-negative) integers form a cancellative semigroup under addition.

Answer (score -1):

Give an example of an infinite semigroup (G,•) in which both left and right cancellation laws hold but (G,•) is not a group.

Let Z*=Z-{0}={...,-2-1,1,2,...}.

Since, Z={...-2,-1,0,1,2,...} under usual addition is a group and Z*⊆Z.

Therefore, (Z*,+) is a semigroup.

Let a,b,c∈Z*, then a+b=a+c ⇒ b=c.

Let if possible b≠c.

Case1: b>c.

a+b=a+c

⇒ (a+b)+(-c)=a

⇒ a+(b-c)=a

Since,

b>c

⇒ b-c>0

⇒ a+(b-c)>a

⇒ a>a.

This is not possible.

Case2: c>b

a+b=a+c

⇒ a=(a+c)+(-b)

⇒ a=a+(c-b)

Since,

c>b

⇒ c-b>0

⇒ a+(c-b)>a

⇒ a>a.

This is not possible.

Thus our assumption that b≠c is wrong.

Hence b=c.

Therefore, left cancellation law hold in (Z*,+)

Similarly one can prove that right cancellation law hold in (Z*,+).

Therefore, (Z*,+) is a semigroup in which both left and right cancellation laws hold, but (Z*,+) is not a group, because 0∉Z*.